What are some examples of algebraic curves with maximum number of real components
Harnack's curve theorem states that for any algebraic curve of degree $m$ in the real projective plane, the number of components $c$ is bounded by $\frac{1-(-1)^m}{2} \le c \le \frac{(m-1)(m-2)}{2}+1$ and that any number of components in this range can be attained.
The Trott curve is an example of a degree 4 curve with the 4 components.
What are some examples of degree 5 curves with 7 components and degree 6 curves with 11 components?
